# ERROR: package name '***' is illegal and cannot be used in message generation

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I add a msg file and build the working space. Add it reports such error. If anyone could help me out? Thanks very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300352/error:-package-name-%27***%27-is-illegal-and-cannot-be-used-in-message-generation./) by [Lemontree](https://answers.ros.org/users/36954/lemontree/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-12**:
Please add your `CMakeLists.txt` and your `package.xml` to your question. Use the `edit` button/link for that.

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2018-08-13**:
What @gvdhoorn wrote, plus - what is the name of your package / msg file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without more information this is going to be difficult to pinpoint exactly, but the error message that you quote comes from `generate_messages(..)` in `genpy/generator.py` ([here](https://github.com/ros/genpy/blob/081cd18a28c968129ab25f2f320bf6908575a65a/src/genpy/generator.py#L975)). It checks whether the package name it's been passed is [a legal ROS name](http://wiki.ros.org/Names) using `genmsg.is_legal_resource_base_name(..)` ([this one](https://github.com/ros/genmsg/blob/490b3753213ed3e2251acd218c62224b2787ee0e/src/genmsg/names.py#L135)).

If that function returns `false`, the name is not legal (ie: contains characters that cannot be used, such as colons or other special characters other than `_` and `-`), the error is printed and message generation is aborted.

You'll have to check whether your package name you used contains any such illegal characters and then change it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2